# Is it possible to input multiple values into a single variable in a Python function?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my function:

```
def function_drop_columns (x,y): 
    return (x).loc[:,~(x).columns.str.endswith(y)]
```

`x` will always just be one input- specifying a dataframe. For `y`, however, there could be many columns I want to drop (which end with different strings). Is there any way to re-write this so `y` can be input with multiple values?

I was wondering if I could input some kind 'or' operator but it doesn't seem to have worked.

```
df1 = function_drop_columns (df,'DATE' or 'STATE')
```

Do I need to change the function itself or is there way to re-write the input to cover different values?

Comment: If you want a variable to hold onto multiple values you need some sort of data structure like an array, tuple, dictionary ... etc. You would have to write logic for your function that would decide which of these values to use.

Comment: So there's no way to do it with just a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` before an argument to pack value in your function like `def function_drop_columns(x, *args):` which pack all value after x like and :

```py
def function_drop_columns(x, *y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

And with that you get in the console :

```py
>>> function_drop_columns("First value", "Second value", "Third value")

First value
('Second value', 'Third value')
```

You can also use `**` if your want to pass value with keyword like :

```py
def function_drop_columns(x, **y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

And we get :

```py
>>> function_drop_columns("First value", second="Second value", third="Third value")

First value
{'second': 'Second value', 'third': 'Third value'}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pandas.Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) allows tuple of strings as pattern. Use could use:

```
function_drop_columns(df, ('DATE', 'STATE'))
```